# how make a register

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I made a recording system but when I click on the register it is inserted 3 4 times in the database, do you have any idea why?

I tried with the debugger to figure out why it is inserted so many times, but the data is taken correctly only because it does not have a correct order. it returns to line 1 and goes to 2 onwards

```
UserRepository :
  public UserModel   insertAccount(string username, string password, string email, int CNP, string firstName, string lastName, int isLogged)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = db.initializare();
            SqlCommand cmd;
            UserModel user=null;
            isLogged = 0;

            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand(Query.registerFunction, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("username", username));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("password", password));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("email", email));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("CNP", CNP));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("firstName", firstName));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("lastName", lastName));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("isLogged", isLogged));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                user = new UserModel(username, password, email, CNP, firstName, lastName, isLogged);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {

                conn.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
            }
            return user;
        }

//
User Servicies: 
 public  UserModel insertAccount(string username,string password,string email,int CNP,string firstName,string lastName,int isLogged)
        {
            UserRepository up = new UserRepository();
            UserModel user = up.insertAccount(username, password, email, CNP, firstName, lastName, isLogged);
            return user;
        }

// user controller 
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        [System.Web.Http.Route("api/userRegister")]
        [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
        public IHttpActionResult userLogOut([FromBody] RegisterModel usr)
        {

            UserServicies us = new UserServicies();
            us.insertAccount(usr.userName,usr.password,usr.email,usr.CNP,usr.firstName,usr.lastName,usr.isLogged);
            return Ok();

        }

// user model 

 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


    public class UserModel
    {
        public int userId;
        public string userName;
        public string password;
        public string email;
        public int isLogged;
        public string statusLogged;
        public string firstName;
        public string lastName;
        public int CNP;



        public UserModel(string userName, string password, string email,int CNP,string firstName,string lastName,int isLogged)
        {
            this.userName = userName;
            this.password = password;
            this.email = email;
            this.CNP = CNP;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.isLogged = isLogged;

        }



        public class RegisterModel
        {
            public string userName;
            public string password;
            public int CNP;
            public string email;
            public string firstName;
            public string lastName;
            public int isLogged;
        }
    }
}
// function register()

function register() {


    var userName = document.getElementById('UserName').value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var CNP = document.getElementById('CNP').value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;

    var userId;
    const fav = {
        username: userName,
        password: password,
        CNP: CNP,
        email: email,
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName:lastName
    };


    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url:"https://localhost:44378/api/userRegister",
        data: JSON.stringify(fav),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
            if (msg) {
            window.location.href = "/login.html";
            }
            else {
                console.log("nope");
            }

        }

    });


}
!!!!!!! REGISTER DONT WORK ( DIRECTLY RUN ELSE BUT IN DATABASE INSERT APPEAR )
//
insert query 
public static string registerFunction = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[users] (username,password,email,CNP,firstName,lastName,isLogged) 
                                            values (@username,@password,@email,@CNP,@firstName,@lastName,@isLogged)";
//
```

Comment: What code calls `insertAccount()`?

Comment: ` Query.cs public static string registerFunction = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[users] (username,password,email,CNP,firstName,lastName,isLogged) 
                                            values (@username,@password,@email,@CNP,@firstName,@lastName,@isLogged)";

Comment: Repository -> Servicies -> Controller

Comment: Hi Bogdan, welcome to SO. You can use the edit button and add the `insertAccount()` code into your question.

Comment: Hi, I put everything in the register function there .. I don't know what code to put

Comment: How many times is it created? 2? 3? 4? Please create a user with brand new attributes and see how many times it is created instead of once.

Comment: SQL Server is multi-process so you need to use a Order By to get queries in a sorted order because data is stored in random order and the query results are random order.  Does the table have a primary key?  When a primary key is used only one entry is allowed for each key.  So if you only want one entry for each userid make userid a primary key.  The use Update to change value of primary key so duplicates are not generated.

Comment: BTW, use `throw`, not `throw ex;`.  The latter erases the original stack trace, hindering your ability to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

it's not very clear why this happens. The reasons can be many from you clicking the button over and over or JavaScript doing multiple calls to that endpoint.

This being said, there are things you can do. First update your code so it does not insert the same thing multiple times. Take your insertAccount method and before you create a new account, make sure the account does not exist already:

```
public  UserModel insertAccount(string username,string password,string email,int CNP,string firstName,string lastName,int isLogged)
        {
            UserRepository up = new UserRepository();

            //do checks here, if account already exist then make your api return a bad request for example.
            UserModel user = up.insertAccount(username, password, email, CNP, firstName, lastName, isLogged);
            return user;
        }
```

Second, use your development tools ( under F12 ) in any browser and check the network activity, this will show you if the end point is called multiple times so you can go and investigate that.

Finally, look at your database, if you should not be able to create accounts with the same email then put a UNIQUE index on the email field, this will prevent accidental inserts from happening.